# How will I sleep?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing on Minecraft Pocket Edition when it was turning dark. I went to sleep, but it said: `"You may not rest now, there are monsters nearby."`

I went up to the roof of my house and saw 1 creeper and 2 skeletons. I killed the creeper and let the skeletons burn in the daylight. The next day, I was tapping really fast and it still said `"You may not rest now, there are monsters nearby."`

I went to the roof again and did not see anything. How do I sleep when there are monsters nearby?

Comment: have you checked around your house, in any unlit basements/caves under your house? the only way to guarantee that no mobs spawn around your house it to build one high in the sky and put torches on the roof

Comment: I'm unsure of the current logic, but it may just be that there are spaces available for monsters to spawn, regardless if there are monsters there already.

Comment: I actually have a mob creater, but I could sleep even with it.

Comment: A mob creator in minecraft pocket edition?

Answer (score 1):

Put lots of torches on and around your home to keep them from spawning on the roof and a good distance from your home.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way you could do this is have a command block in your house (get by doing

```
/give @p command_block
```

in the chat and do this command

```
/kill @e[name=!changethistoyourname,r=30]
```

it will kill any mobs or players except for you with in 30 blocks of the command block.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you could try placing torches around your house, and putting your bed in the middle of your house. If the mobs are on the roof, you could place torches on the roof, raise the roof a little higher, or make the roof out of glass. This decreases the chance of mobs being nearby when you're trying to sleep.